# Reserve file descriptors to guard against FD exhaustion

Tags: python

I have a python application with multiple threads, with threads 2 to n potentially opening an arbitrary number of files. I want to make sure that when thread 1 tries to open a file, it will definitely not fail because of file descriptor exhaustion. In short, I want to reserve file descriptors without opening them.
I can only control the code being run from thread 1, which is spawned at a time when there's still plenty of file descriptors left.

(As an example, I imagine this could be done by 'reserving' fds by opening /dev/null a couple of times from thread 1, and closing it when thread 1 needs to open a file, thus making sure that there's at least one unused fd, but this ends up introducing a race condition.)

Is there a way to make sure thread 1 will have fds available when it needs them without modifying what threads 2-n do?

Comment: Is your question "can I reserve fds in this way"? (implied by "I imagine"), or is it "how can I avoid a race?"   Those are separate questions - there's a one-question-per-post limit :)

Comment: The main question is "can I reserve fds, and if so, how", the "how can I avoid a race" only applies to the racy example solution.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to achieve. If you finish the fds it doesn't matter whether you have a `mutex` etc., other threads will fail because they cannot write to a file. You could simply write your custom `open` replacement that in case of missing fds sends the thread to sleep a bit and retries until it works (or up to `n` times). In this way you can handle the situation without having to insert special-case code in the logic of the threads.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a mutex.  For python 2.x that's the [mutex](http://docs.python.org/2/library/mutex.html) or [thread](http://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html#module-thread) module.

In your "thread 1" you will access (obtain/lock) the mutex first, then close the reserved fd and open the real one, then release the mutex.

In your other threads, you simply wait till you can get the mutex, then open the file, then release the mutex.

For python3 it's the Lock from the [threading](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module.

(Note: I'm not commenting on whether or not opening /dev/null achieves what you want in terms of reserving an fd, because I'm not confident about that.  I'm just providing you a solution for how to avoid the race that you askeded about :) ).

Comment: I don't have control over what the other threads do, they may come from untrusted plugins. They are allowed to execute arbitrary code.

Comment: Then you can't protect yourself against a race with them, AFAICS.   This means you need a solution more like Bakuriu's suggestion.   In fact, that seems like a good, pythonic solution: if you fail, sleep then retry.